# Springboot app not responding after @Scheduled cron run

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, cron, health-monitoring

I have a Springboot service with a `@Scheduled` cron run at 2:30 AM. During the cron run, I try to do some DB operations, which fetch a lot of data in memory and I face a Java heap error while extracting the result set. However, since this happens in the `scheduling-1` thread, I expect my Springboot app to function healthily and respond to health-check pings as expected.

However, (most of the times, NOT ALL) this happens:

1. My Springboot app stops responding to health-check pings. It stops responding to any CURL requests.
2. However my other crons that subsequently run on the `scheduling-1` thread, run successfully.
3. I use hourly `logrotate` policy to write to logs. I see that the Springboot app(except the `scheduled-1` thread) stops writing to logs, the log files only get created for the hours in which some crons are scheduled. For the other hours, the log files are missing. So for example, the current log files I have for today are `application.2020-03-26_00.0.log  application.2020-03-26_01.0.log  application.2020-03-26_02.0.log  application.2020-03-26_04.0.log  application.2020-03-26_06.0.log` . You can see how there is no log for 3 AM and 5 AM, because there were crons run at 4 AM and at 6 AM.
4. When I run `lsof -i : 8080` to view if my service is still listening to this port (considering that it gives a `Connection reset by peer` failure on any CURL), I get the following output.

```
COMMAND   PID   USER   FD   TYPE   DEVICE SIZE/OFF NODE NAME
java    24980 deploy  475u  IPv4 79544043      0t0  TCP *:http-alt (LISTEN)
java    24980 deploy  601u  IPv4 80098922      0t0  TCP ip-x-x-x-x.ap-southeast-1.compute.internal:http-alt->ip-x-x-x-x.ap-southeast-1.compute.internal:30616 (CLOSE_WAIT)
```

Whereas on the other box on which the 2:30 AM cron did not run and is functioning healthily, the same `lsof` command returns this:

```
COMMAND   PID   USER   FD   TYPE   DEVICE SIZE/OFF NODE NAME
java    28975 deploy  184u  IPv4 71997654      0t0  TCP ip-x-x-x-x.ap-southeast-1.compute.internal:http-alt->ip-x-x-x-x.ap-southeast-1.compute.internal:58560 (ESTABLISHED)
java    28975 deploy  198u  IPv4 72011154      0t0  TCP ip-x-x-x-x.ap-southeast-1.compute.internal:http-alt->ip-x-x-x-x.ap-southeast-1.compute.internal:51588 (ESTABLISHED)
java    28975 deploy  278u  IPv4 72010749      0t0  TCP ip-x-x-x-x.ap-southeast-1.compute.internal:http-alt->ip-x-x-x-x.ap-southeast-1.compute.internal:41256 (ESTABLISHED)
java    28975 deploy  484u  IPv4 71536371      0t0  TCP *:http-alt (LISTEN)
```

As you can see, on the box where the application is not responding to web requests, there is only one listening connection and one connection in CLOSE_WAIT state, where as in the healthy box, there are 3 ESTABLISHED connections.

Lastly, this only happens like 90% of the times. The other 10%, the service where the cron ran at 2:30 AM and threw the JDBC exception, continues to function healthily. This makes the situation even more puzzling.

Could anyone please help me understand why in the affected box, there are no established connections. Also, could the JDBC exception in the `scheduling-1` thread be causing this issue? Then how come the `shceduling-1` thread is able to run other crons successfully?

Here is the relevant part of stacktrace of the JDB exception, if this helps:

```
com.zaxxer.hikari.pool.ProxyConnection:153 - HikariPool-1 - Connection com.mysql.cj.jdbc.ConnectionImpl@4fa3351a marked as broken because of SQLSTATE(08007), ErrorCode(0)
java.sql.SQLNonTransientConnectionException: Communications link failure during rollback(). Transaction resolution unknown.
        at com.mysql.cj.jdbc.exceptions.SQLError.createSQLException(SQLError.java:110)
        at com.mysql.cj.jdbc.exceptions.SQLError.createSQLException(SQLError.java:97)
        at com.mysql.cj.jdbc.exceptions.SQLError.createSQLException(SQLError.java:89)
        at com.mysql.cj.jdbc.exceptions.SQLError.createSQLException(SQLError.java:63)
        at com.mysql.cj.jdbc.ConnectionImpl.rollback(ConnectionImpl.java:1846)
        at com.zaxxer.hikari.pool.ProxyConnection.rollback(ProxyConnection.java:370)
        at com.zaxxer.hikari.pool.HikariProxyConnection.rollback(HikariProxyConnection.java)
        at org.hibernate.resource.jdbc.internal.AbstractLogicalConnectionImplementor.rollback(AbstractLogicalConnectionImplementor.java:116)
        at org.hibernate.resource.transaction.backend.jdbc.internal.JdbcResourceLocalTransactionCoordinatorImpl$TransactionDriverControlImpl.rollback(JdbcResourceLocalTransactionCoordinatorImpl.java:294)
        at org.hibernate.engine.transaction.internal.TransactionImpl.rollback(TransactionImpl.java:145)
        at org.springframework.orm.jpa.JpaTransactionManager.doRollback(JpaTransactionManager.java:559)
        at org.springframework.transaction.support.AbstractPlatformTransactionManager.processRollback(AbstractPlatformTransactionManager.java:838)
        at org.springframework.transaction.support.AbstractPlatformTransactionManager.rollback(AbstractPlatformTransactionManager.java:812)
        at org.springframework.transaction.interceptor.TransactionAspectSupport.completeTransactionAfterThrowing(TransactionAspectSupport.java:552)
        at org.springframework.transaction.interceptor.TransactionAspectSupport.invokeWithinTransaction(TransactionAspectSupport.java:299)
        at org.springframework.transaction.interceptor.TransactionInterceptor.invoke(TransactionInterceptor.java:98)
        at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:186)
        at org.springframework.dao.support.PersistenceExceptionTranslationInterceptor.invoke(PersistenceExceptionTranslationInterceptor.java:139)
        at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:186)
        at org.springframework.data.jpa.repository.support.CrudMethodMetadataPostProcessor$CrudMethodMetadataPopulatingMethodInterceptor.invoke(CrudMethodMetadataPostProcessor.java:144)
        at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:186)
        at org.springframework.data.jpa.repository.support.CrudMethodMetadataPostProcessor$ExposeRepositoryInvocationInterceptor.invoke(CrudMethodMetadataPostProcessor.java:364)
        at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:186)
        at org.springframework.aop.interceptor.ExposeInvocationInterceptor.invoke(ExposeInvocationInterceptor.java:93)
        at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:186)
        at org.springframework.data.repository.core.support.SurroundingTransactionDetectorMethodInterceptor.invoke(SurroundingTransactionDetectorMethodInterceptor.java:61)
        at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:186)
        at org.springframework.aop.framework.JdkDynamicAopProxy.invoke(JdkDynamicAopProxy.java:212)
        at com.sun.proxy.$Proxy218.deleteAll(Unknown Source)
```

Comment: Fix your processing, as that is the issue. It leads to a memory-leak , leading to excessive GC, leading to a totally unresponsive application. So fix your batch processing (which seems to be wrong in the first place as why load eveything in memory?). You shouldalso fix your idle checking of the connections (which will prevent the error you have once in a while).

Comment: There does not seem to be a memory leak. The memory profile is back to normal after GC runs. And the GC is not running more after the cron run. 

Also, it is the Spring JPA code which is loading everything in memory even for a delete command. I am fixing that. Also, the health-check cannot be paused as it is company wide.

Comment: If there is a lot of memory occupied, it will start to do massive GC (you can enable GC logging). It isn't the JPA code but how you are deleting things (if it is only a delete it should be a delete query and not a `deleteById` or `deleteAllById`. Nonetheless you also have an issue with your connection pool, for which you should enable checking idle connections (you need a max poolsize different from the initial poolsize and a max time for the connection). That will clean the pool and/or refresh stale connections.

Comment: I just verified that Spring JPA does a findAll even for deleteAll ,so it is JPA code. Also, I will check how to set a max timeout for connections in Hikari, which Spring is using here.

Comment: Yes and there is also a note in the documentation that you shouldn't use that for large amounts of data because it is slow.

Comment: Still , if I could get a clear reason why there are no spring boot active connections established to 8080, once the JDBC exception occurs, that would be nice. As in, if it can be proved that the JDBC exception causes the springboot connections to close. Because the number of connections to AWS RDS do not vary at all during the cron run, when the exception is thrown.

Comment: Your batch is getting a connection and not sure how large your pool is.

Comment: Mixing the batch job with a web service seems like a very bad idea to me.  I would separate the two.  No kicking off cron jobs from web services.  I'd put the batch job on a completely different server.  Your batch job sounds like it needs a good review, too.  OOME?  That's very bad indeed.  I'm betting that you are trying to process a ResultSet that is far too large.  You need to break it into chunks.